# Apache tomcat mutual authentication self signed certificate REST service

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, x509certificate, mutual-authentication

I want to deploy my REST service (war) on Apache Tomcat, want it to enable HTTPS using self signed certificate and mutual authentication. I need to come up with a client that uses self-signed certificate. I want the client and servers to exchange their certificates.

I need suggestion as to how this can be done.

Answer (score -1):

The tomcat connector configuration which does all you need, typically looks like below

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="want" connectionTimeout="20000"  
keystoreFile="C:\\Users\\tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
keystoreType="JKS" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"  
scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" truststoreFile="C:\\Users
\\tomcat.truststore" truststorePass="changeit" truststoreType="JKS"/>
```

This link will be very full to understand the terminology
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

From your application perspective you application should accept https connection should be able to allow client authentication using certificate.

hope this gives you some hint!